# use sql to find average rating given by each user

Tags: sql

The task asks me to use proc sql to find average rating given by each user that have reviewed more than 5 recipes. and datasets are below:

```
user_id   recipe_id   date           rating
231        245        17/02/2019      20 
098        134        31/01/2019      1
.......
.......
```

Could anyone show me how to get the result please?

Thank you very much

Comment: Please add the query you tried and the problems you have with it. We don't do your homework for you

Comment: I stand corrected. We do your homework for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Aggregate function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/aggregate-functions-in-sql/) effectively to achieve these.

Try Below

```
SELECT recipe_id, AVG(rating)
FROM Table1
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT user_id, COUNT(recipe_id) FROM Table1 GROUP BY user_id HAVING COUNT(recipe_id) > 5)
GROUP BY recipe_id
```

Comment: One could argue if you are supporting the lazyness if the OP. But what I think is more important: your answer could be improved by adding an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to only return users with more than different 5 recipes.

```
SELECT user_id, AVG(rating)
FROM tablename
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(distinct recipe_id) > 5
```

Do `COUNT(distinct recipe_id) > 5` to return only users with more than 5 different recipes reviewed. (As suggested by Serge.)

`COUNT(recipe_id) > 5` could include same recipe several times.

Comment: `COUNT( DISTINCT recipe_id)` probably in a case when a user can review a reciept several times.

Comment: @Serg, makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @jarlh . . . You should only use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` if duplicates are allowed.  Otherwise it imposes unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, since _I_ don't have the table definition here, I'll let OP chose.

Answer (score 0):

try this using sql join

```
SELECT 
    r.user_id
    ,AVG(rating) avg
FROM recipe r
inner join (
        Select user_id
    from recipe 
    group by user_id
    having count(*) > 5
) c
on c.user_id =r.user_id
group by r.user_id
```